# JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-11

When I changed *jdk* in my project from 8 to 11 I have cought this problem:

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58645', transport: 'socket'
>   Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58645', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>desktop-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>Terminal</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>version.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>font/*.ttf</include>
                    <include>fxml/**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.png</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.svg</include>
                    <include>sound/*.wav</include>
                    <include>style/**/*.css</include>
                    <include>bundle/*.properties</include>
                    <include>testdata/*.*</include>
                    <include>com/**/*</include>
                    <include>welcome/**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>version.txt</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <mainClass>com.desktop.terminal.App</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/ribbon-1.0.jar lib/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ribbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/static/lib/ribbon-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.14</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/static/lib/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric.centerdevice</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafxsvg</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JFREECHART -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart-fx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- external API dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- client maven -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.novsys</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib_uni-analysis</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcprov-ext-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcpkix-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sourceforge-igetdb</id>
            <name>igetdb repository as joone source</name>
            <url>http://igetdb.sourceforge.net/maven2-repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

How you can see I added *javafx dependency*, but application doesn't work.

Comment: Are you making a fat jar? Then you need to use a Launcher class that doesn't extend from `Application`, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).

Comment: The required dependencies depend on the classes you reference in your code. For example class `javafx.application.Application` is part of module `javafx.graphics`, which I did not see in the _pom.xml_ that you posted. I'm assuming your _JavaFX_ application references class `Application`. I'm assuming, since I didn't see any code in your post. As far as I know, **all** _JavaFX_ applications **must** reference class `Application`, so your _pom.xml_ is at least missing the `javafx.graphics` dependency.

Comment: @Abra Maven transitive dependencies are resolved. For instance, having `javafx.controls` gives you `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.base`.